Supremum norm is a measurable norm (in the sense of Gross) on classical Wiener space
I am trying to verify Example 2 from the following excerpt of "Abstract Wiener Spaces" by L. Gross  
The context is that we consider a Hilbert space $H$, which I will assume to be separable, and a space of measurable functions on a probability space $L^0(\Omega, \mathbb{P})$ together with a linear function $F: H \longrightarrow L^0(\Omega, \mathbb{P})$. This linear function associates to each $x \in H$ a Gaussian random variable $F(x) \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \|x\|^2)$ such that $(F(x_j)_{j=1,\dots,n}) \sim \mathcal{N}(0, (\langle x_i, x_j \rangle)_{i,j=1,\dots,n})$. Then for any function $\phi \circ P: H \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $P$ is the projection onto a finite dimensional subspace $P H = span(e_1, \dots, e_n)$, we define a random variable
$$
(\phi \circ P)^\sim = \phi\Big( \sum_{j=1}^n F(e_j) e_j \Big) \,.
$$
We can without loss of generality assume the $e_j$ to be an orthonormal system. My understanding is that a seminorm $\|\cdot\|_1$ is measurable if and only if there exists an ONB $(e_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $H$ such that $\forall\, \epsilon > 0 \quad \exists\, n > 0 \quad \forall\, m > 0$ we have
$$
\mathbb{P}\Big( \Big\| \sum_{j=n}^m F(e_j) e_j \Big\|_1 > \epsilon \Big) < \epsilon \,.
$$
This could also be phrased as the series $\sum_{j=1}^\infty F(e_j) e_j$ converging in probability with respect to $\|\cdot\|_1$.
For Example 1 this works beautifully:
$$
\mathbb{E} \Big[ \Big\langle A \sum_{j=n}^m F(e_j) e_j, \sum_{j=n}^m F(e_j) e_j \Big\rangle \Big]
= \sum_{j=n}^m \langle A e_j, e_j \rangle \underset{= 1}{\mathbb{E}[|F(e_j)|^2]} \,,
$$
so we have convergence in $L^1$ which implies convergence in probability. For Example 2 I do not see how it can be true though. Here $C'$ is the space of absolutely continuous functions $f: [0, 1] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(0) = 0$, equipped with the inner product
$$
\langle f, g \rangle_{C'} = \int_0^1 f'(t) g'(t) dt \,.
$$
My best attempt is
$$
\sup_{t \in [0, 1]} \Big| \sum_{j=n}^m F(e_j) e_j(t) \Big| \leq C_{Sobolev} \Big\| \sum_{j=n}^m F(e_j) e_j(t) \Big\|_{L^2_{t \in [0, 1]}} = C_{Sobolev} \Big( \sum_{j=n}^m |F(e_j)|^2 \Big)^{\frac12},
$$
and here the sum on the right is a random variable whose distribution depends only on $m - n$. Am I missing something with the whole setup or is the solution simply that a more subtle estimate is necessary than the Sobolev embedding?

The solution is to not use the Sobolev embedding, which is too coarse, but instead compute the actual eigenfunctions $e_j$ and note that they have some $\|\dot\|_{L^\infty}$ decay in $j$. Then everything follows as it should.
